# MySQL find user rank for each category

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have the following table:

```
 user_id | category_id | points
 -------------------------------
       1 |           1 | 4
       2 |           1 | 2
       2 |           1 | 5
       1 |           2 | 3
       2 |           2 | 2
       1 |           3 | 1
       2 |           3 | 4
       1 |           3 | 8
```

Could someone please help me to construct a query to return user's rank per category - something like this:

```
user_id | category_id | total_points | rank
-------------------------------------------
      1 |           1 |            4 |    2
      1 |           2 |            3 |    1
      1 |           3 |            9 |    1
      2 |           1 |            7 |    1
      2 |           2 |            2 |    2
      2 |           3 |            4 |    2
```

Comment: Use SELECT user_id, category_id, sum(points) as total_points FROM table GROUP BY user_id, category_id for the first 3 columns ...

Comment: Check out this fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/317da3/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to get the total points per category.  Then you need to enumerate them.  In MySQL this is most easily done with variables:

```
SELECT user_id, category_id, points,
       (@rn := if(@cat = category_id, @rn + 1,
                  if(@cat := category_id, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as rank
FROM (SELECT u.user_id, u.category_id, SUM(u.points) as points
      FROM users u
      GROUP BY u.user_id, u.category_id
     ) g cross join
     (SELEct @user := -1, @cat := -1, @rn := 0) vars
ORDER BY category_id, points desc;
```

Comment: This demonstrates the use of user_variables, but ... the GROUP BY clause in `g` needs to be `u.category_id, u.user_id`. And there's no need to initialize `@user`. (I was confused by the second IF expression  in `rank`,  but then I realized that's not really intended to be a conditional test, that's just where the assignment of category_id to the user-defined variable is being made.)

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . Those problems are fixed.  The purpose of the nested `if` is because MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions, so all the variable assignments are in one expression.

Comment: +1 Right, I understand that MySQL doesn't guarantee the order of evaluation; MySQL doesn't guarantee that user-defined variables will "work" the way we see them working. Nice trick of putting that assignment into an `IF()` expression. (The approach I use is to order the expressions in the SELECT list so the the `category_id` column after the `rank` column, and I do the assignment on the line that returns the `category_id` column, but I like the approach you use.

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the `SUM` of points for each unique `category_id`:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.category_id, SUM(u.points)
FROM users AS u
GROUP BY uc.category_id
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have analytic functions like other databases (Oracle, SQL Server) which would be very convenient for returning a result like this.

The first three columns are straightforward, just `GROUP BY user_id, category_id` and a `SUM(points)`.

Getting the `rank` column returned is a bit more of a problem. Aside from doing that on the client, if you need to do that in the SQL statement, you could make use of MySQL user-defined variables.

```
SELECT @rank := IF(@prev_category = r.category_id, @rank+1, 1) AS rank 
     , @prev_category := r.category_id AS category_id
     , r.user_id
     , r.total_points
  FROM (SELECT @prev_category := NULL, @rank := 1) i 
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT s.category_id, s.user_id, SUM(s.points) AS total_points
           FROM users s
         GROUP BY s.category_id, s.user_id
         ORDER BY s.category_id, total_points DESC
       ) r
ORDER BY r.category_id, r.total_points DESC, r.user_id DESC
```

The purpose of the inline view aliased as `i` is to initialize user defined variables. The inline view aliased as `r` returns the total_points for each (user_id, category_id).

The "trick" is to compare the category_id value of the previous row with the value of the current row; if they match, we increment the rank by 1. If it's a "new" category, we reset the rank to 1. Note this only works if the rows are ordered by category, and then by total_points descending, so we need the ORDER BY clause. Also note that the order of the expressions in the SELECT list is important; we need to do the comparison of the previous value BEFORE it's overwritten with the current value, so the assignment to @prev_category must follow the conditional test.

Also note that if two users have the same total_points in a category, they will get distinct values for rank... the query above doesn't give the same rank for a tie. (The query could be modified to do that as well, but we'd also need to preserve total_points from the previous row, so we can compare to the current row.

Also note that this syntax is specific to MySQL, and that this is behavior is *not* guaranteed.

---

If you need the columns in the particular sequence and/or the rows in a particular order (to get the exact resultset specified), we'd need to wrap the query above as an inline view.

```
SELECT t.user_id
     , t.category_id
     , t.total_points
     , t.rank 
  FROM (
         SELECT @rank := IF(@prev_category = r.category_id, @rank+1, 1) AS rank 
              , @prev_category := r.category_id AS category_id
              , r.user_id
              , r.total_points
           FROM (SELECT @prev_categor := NULL, @rank := 1) i 
          CROSS
           JOIN ( SELECT s.category_id, s.user_id, SUM(s.points) AS total_points
                    FROM users s
                  GROUP BY s.category_id, s.user_id
                  ORDER BY s.category_id, total_points DESC
                ) r
         ORDER BY r.category_id, r.total_points DESC, r.user_id DESC
      ) t
  ORDER BY t.user_id, t.category_id
```

NOTE: I've *not* setup a SQL Fiddle demonstration. I've given an example query which has only been desk checked.